# How to set Action Bar Sherlock to the bottom like TabBar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I haven't found any parameters than can do so. I tried abs__dimens.xml, but it seems that i need something another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, unless you want to create a custom implementation of it, modifying it entirely. Besides that: The ActionBar is meant to be at the top of the screen, giving the user an "anker point", so he can navigate through the app.